# SHELL SCRIPT : How can I make a program that looks for a word through all pages from a site

Tags: shell

This is what I got , but it works only for 1 page from a site.How can I look for more than 1 page?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Type the URL:"
read site
ping -c 3 $site > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ $? -ne 0 ] 
then
echo "URL NOT FOUND "
else
echo "What word do you want to search?"
read exp
echo "$exp was found"
lynx -dump -nolist "$site" | grep -c -i "$exp"
echo "times"
fi
```

Comment: You need to get URLs of each page and scan them in loop

Comment: you should consider to use python script to do it, using scrapy and beautifulsoup

Comment: I need this for my class and if i have a list with all URLs how can i make a loop